# JPA : Many to many relationship in Google App

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, many-to-many, google-cloud-datastore

I'm *beginner* of Google app. I want to know how to code many to many relationship for JPA in Google app. Could u give me the example? I'm trying to connect **Order, Order_Item and Product**.

Answer (score 2):

GAE has a [complete walkthrough](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jpa/overview.html) of using JPA in GAE. You should hardly need to come here asking for someone to write the code for you.

Comment: Sorry, if my question mean like that. Thanks for link.